Question about IVP involving function with separated formulae
Consider a problem like
$$ y''+y'+y = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}g(t), & t<c \\ f(t), & t\geq c\end{array}\right. $$
$$ y'(0)=a, \quad y(0)=b.$$
So the way we solve this in class is by rewritting the function on the right hand side with a heaviside function combination, like $g(t)+H(t-c)(f(t)-g(t))$ then applying Laplace transform on both sides. The result yields a solution that satisfies the IVP with $g$ before $t=c$ and equals to $f$ when $t>c$.
But my question is: can't one also write two different IVPs, one
$$ y''+y'+y = g(t),$$
$$ y'(0)=a, \quad y(0)=b$$ find the solution $y_1(t)$, then write another problem
$$ y''+y'+y = f(t),$$
$$ y'(0)=a, \quad y(0)=b,$$ find the solution $y_2(t)$, then state that $y$ is equals to $y_1$ if $t<c$ and $y_2$ otherwise? Would this be the same thing?
Or is there a problem with this reasoning, since I'm not exactly computing a solution that satisfies both constraints simultaneously for each of the two problems? Would there be a problem with that? Because since the Laplace transform of the Heaviside function is so particular, it doesn't seem like these methods would yield the same results...

Almost. The solution would still be expected to be maximally smooth, so the patching condition is
$$
y_2(c)=y_1(c),\\
y_2'(c)=y_1'(c).
$$
